# Restrict user to open particular pages on multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I want to restrict users from opening a particular form in more than one tab. In my application there are many forms but I want to do this validation only for some of the forms.

- I don't want to use "Session" for this.
- I want to do this validation on client side.

I have searched for this topic but everywhere the solution says to make use of `window.open`, but I am not opening my forms using `window.open` instead we have menus containing links to all of the forms.

Comment: Validation clientside is far too easy to hack though, depending on how important these tabs are to your system, I'd consider both - always. Just as a comment.

Comment: I agree. I don't know *why* you don't want to use sessions but this would be the right way to do it (unless there are certain undisclosed reasons why you don't want that).

Comment: I agree with @PedroG.Dias Always do both, client and server

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If I use session , how will I differentiate that my page is refreshed or the same page having same URL is opened in another tab.